# Cannot instantiate interface org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener after adding spring-security-oauth2

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

After I added `spring-security-oauth2` to my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

I started to get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot instantiate interface org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener : org.springframework.boot.context.logging.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:439)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:418)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:409)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<init>(SpringApplication.java:268)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<init>(SpringApplication.java:247)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1245)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1233)
```

after running my `@SpringBootApplication`. Please note that I am using Spring Boot 2.0.0.M5 and I think that this might be the root of the problem (w.r.t. versions).

This is the entire pom.xml I'm using:;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <artifactId>server</artifactId>
        <groupId>mahlzeit</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>api</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <spring.boot.version>2.0.0.M5</spring.boot.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Spring Framework Boot -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Framework -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.4.1208-jdbc42-atlassian-hosted</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <!-- Required since this is currently using Spring RC version -->
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

</project>
```

I have the suspicion this might have to do with conflicting versions - most answers on stackoverflow turn out to be just that - but I cannot make out the actual issue I am having here.

---

The [release notes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0.0-M5-Release-Notes) for Spring Boot 2.0.0.M5 state:

> **OAuth 2.0 Support**
>   Functionality from the Spring Security OAuth project is being migrated to core Spring Security. OAuth 2.0 client support has already been added and additional features will be migrated in due course.
>   If you depend on Spring Security OAuth features that have not yet been migrated you will need to add `org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2` and configure things manually. If you only need OAuth 2.0 client support you can use the auto-configuration provided by Spring Boot 2.0. We’re also continuing to support Spring Boot 1.5 so older applications can continue to use that until an upgrade path is provided.

Comment: Where is your spring boot settings code ? put them too.

Comment: I mean your `autoconfiguration`. And where is your parent tag ? please put the full `pom.xml`.

Comment: I didn't see any packaging information in your pom. My build plugin looks like https://pastebin.com/Ghcd7tWa

Comment: @AtaurRahmanMunna Well, I boiled it down to `spring-security-oauth2` - thus I updated my question accordingly. It seems that adding this dependency will cause this issue and I don't see why. I need classes like `TokenStore` and `JwtAccessTokenConverter` for access token security but well .. it doesn't run with that dependency.

Comment: Unfortunately, the example doesn't work. The pom is missing several versions and the configuration of Boot's Maven plugin is incomplete.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson What do you mean by several versions? Can you explain what you mean by incomplete?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Having fixed the problems with the example's pom, I can now see the complete stack trace of the failure:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot instantiate interface org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener : org.springframework.boot.context.logging.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:439)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:418)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:409)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<init>(SpringApplication.java:268)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<init>(SpringApplication.java:247)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1245)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1233)
    at mahlzeit.api.Application.main(Application.java:14)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/event/GenericApplicationListener
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:255)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:431)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.context.event.GenericApplicationListener
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 21 more
```

The root cause of the problem is that `org.springframework.context.event.GenericApplicationListener` isn't on the classpath. This class is part of the `spring-context` module and is new in Spring Framework 4.2.

Looking at the pom, you're not using Boot's dependency management (either by importing the `spring-boot-dependencies` bom or by using `spring-boot-starter-parent` as your project's parent. This means that the versions of any transitive dependencies aren't being managed. That's causing the problem here as your project is using 4.0.9.RELEASE of `spring-context` transitively via `spring-security-oauth2`.

I would strongly recommend that you use Spring Boot's dependency management. If you don't want to do that or can't do that for some unstated reason, you will have to manually ensure that all transitive dependencies have supported versions.

Comment: That did it! Thank you - I wouldn't have thought of that.

Comment: Thanks for updating this link on github issue

Answer (score 2):

Updating the Maven Project resolved my issue..

Right Click on your `Project` -> `Maven` -> `Update Project` 
or Shortcut `Alt+F5`

Select `Force Update of Snapshots/Releases`

[image]

Comment: Worked for me too, issue occured after pulling some totally POM-unrelated changes. Just Eclipse "completely normal phenomenon".

Answer (score 2):

I was having this issue using Gradle+Kotlin. The solution was to set the version of the Spring Boot Gradle Plugin in my library and in my main project to the same value:

```
plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.2.2.RELEASE"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following configuration and hope it will solve the problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>YOUR GROUP ID</groupId>
<artifactId>ART ID</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>YOUR PROJECT NAME</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>
....
[YOUR REST OF CONFIGURATIONS]
....
</project>
```

Good Luck ! Salam