# I cant use Spring Framework on my PC

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea

Do you know how to make it work? It is clean spring-boot script without any edits, so I don't know what the hell is wrong. Only thing i have done is reinstall JDK and I dont know what more can I do.

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
}
}
```

This is error message:

```
"D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\bin\java.exe" -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 -noverify -Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=50742 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localhost -Dspring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain -Dspring.application.admin.enabled=true "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1.1\lib\idea_rt.jar=50743:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1.1\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\charsets.jar;D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\deploy.jar;D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\javaws.jar;D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\jce.jar;D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\jfr.jar;D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\jsse.jar;D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\plugin.jar;D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\resources.jar;D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Users\Kordian\Desktop\demo1\target\classes;C:\Users\Kordian\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter\2.0.1.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Kordian\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\2.0.1.RELEASE\spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Kordian\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\5.0.5.RELEASE\spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Kordian\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\5.0.5.RELEASE\spring-aop-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Kordian\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\5.0.5.RELEASE\spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Kordian\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\5.0.5.RELEASE\spring-expression-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Kordian\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\2.0.1.RELEASE\spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Kordian\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-logging\2.0.1.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-logging-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Kordian\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-classic\1.2.3\logback-classic-1.2.3.jar;C:\Users\Kordian\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-core\1.2.3\logback-core-1.2.3.jar;C:\Users\Kordian\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-to-slf4j\2.10.0\log4j-to-slf4j-2.10.0.jar;C:\Users\Kordian\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.10.0\log4j-api-2.10.0.jar;C:\Users\Kordian\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\1.7.25\jul-to-slf4j-1.7.25.jar;C:\Users\Kordian\.m2\repository\javax\annotation\javax.annotation-api\1.3.2\javax.annotation-api-1.3.2.jar;C:\Users\Kordian\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\5.0.5.RELEASE\spring-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Kordian\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jcl\5.0.5.RELEASE\spring-jcl-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Kordian\.m2\repository\org\yaml\snakeyaml\1.19\snakeyaml-1.19.jar;C:\Users\Kordian\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.25\slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar" com.example.demo.DemoApplication
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot instantiate interface org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListener : org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:448)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:427)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getRunListeners(SpringApplication.java:413)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243)
    at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:10)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/aop/framework/AopProxyUtils
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:182)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:444)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/aop/framework/AopProxyUtils
    at org.springframework.context.event.AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.addApplicationListener(AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.java:108)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.<init>(EventPublishingRunListener.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:170)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.aop.framework.AopProxyUtils
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 14 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Comment: better include error message and code to the post instead of posting a screenshot.  Also describe what attempts you have made so far

Comment: The only thing i done is JDK reinstall, I added code and error message to post.

Comment: Show me your spring and boot versions in pom

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot instantiate interface org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener after adding spring-security-oauth2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47000066/cannot-instantiate-interface-org-springframework-context-applicationlistener-aft)

Answer (score 1):

Problem with spring related dependency versions. 
Check your sring boot and spring version compatibility.

Comment: I added pom.xml to post.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, my problem was easier than i thought. Bugged files in maven repository, I repaired it this way

1.Delete repository folder in .m3/

2.Then right mouse button on project -> Maven -> Download Sources

3.Now everything is ok!